# Is it safe to disable SSL verification for downloading files? (Python)

Tags: python, ssl, url, https, ssl-certificate

I am wanting to download a file from a very well known website. I checked the certificate for the website and it is there, with proper expiration date and all, but when trying in Python:

```
url_data = 'https://archive.physionet.org/pn6/chbmit/chb01/chb01_04.edf'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_data, 'data.edf')
```

I get the following error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1125)>
```

So as a work around I disable the verification check.

Is this dangerous? this could potentially be used by other people, does it pose a security risk? and does changing `https` to `http` do the same thing? since it works!

Comment: Yes it is dangerous, and yes it could be used by attackers, and yes it poses a security risk, and no changing HTTPS to HTTP does not do the same thing, but it is equally insecure.

Comment: @user207421 is this only whilst the download is taking place?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I have no experience on this matter, and was thinking encryption keys (although might not be relevant to this at all!) but condescension for answering questions from people with no experience has never helped anyone :).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Actually if the OP download something executable a MITM attacker might embed a malware into it and harm the computer later

Comment: Anyway -- if you want to be safe then read on general issues with HTTP, figure out what exactly is going on and actually fix the issue. (although the fix might not on topic here)